# Show that $a^{\varphi(n)+1}\equiv a,\mod n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Euler theorem says that if $a$ and $n$ are coprime, then
$$a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1,\mod n.$$
How do we infer from this that
$$a^{\varphi(n)+1}\equiv a,\mod n,$$
for all $a$?

---

Try: If $a$ and $n$ are coprime then
$$a^{\varphi(n)+1}\equiv a^{\varphi(n)}\times a\equiv 1\times a\equiv a,\mod n.$$
But what if they are not coprime?

Comment: If $(a,n)\gt 1$ then something else happens, and for all $k\gt 0, a^k\not\equiv 1\pmod n$...

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily true when $a$ and $n$ are not coprime. Take $n = 8$ and $a = 2$. Then $\phi(n) = \phi(8) = 4$, but $$2^{\phi(8)+1} = 2^5 = 32 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Take $a=2$ and $n=4$. Then, $\varphi(n)=2$ and
$$a^{\varphi(n)+1}=2^3=8\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$
while $2\not\equiv 0\pmod{4}$.

Comment: It seems that our edits collided.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for the \pmod trick.